# Add product alerts for "out of stock" associated products

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, alert

In **Magento 1.9.2.4**, I would like to display product alerts for associated products even though other associated products for the configurable product are in stock. For example, I have shoes in sizes 5-14. We are out of stock in just a few sizes, 7.5 and 9. I would like to have the product alert come notify them when those 2 sizes become available.

Unfortunately the product alerts do not show up if there is at least one associated product in stock for the configurable group.

Does anyone know how to set up the product alerts so customer can be notified when the size they want comes back in stock.

Thank you